# How to make the first element of a void* equal to 1 when it's casted as a char*?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm new to C, so I'm still trying to get used to some of the concepts, so apologies if this sounds like a dumb question.

I'm given a void pointer, and I have to check that if the first element of it is equal to 1 when casting it as a char pointer. I basically have to solve the following:

```
void* ptr;
//Ensure that ((char*)ptr)[0] == 1
```

So far, what I have is:

```
void* ptr = malloc(4);
char* temp = "f";
ptr = temp;
```

I'm still trying to get used to comparing chars and ints in C. I recently learned that it compares their ASCII values. Wouldn't that mean that the since the first number in the ASCII value for "f" is 1 (102), it would mean that `((char*)ptr)[0] == 1`? This is probably wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I also know that the C char with an ASCII value of exactly 1 is `^A`. I'm not sure how to enter that in as a char* since it just interprets the whole thing as two chars (the `^` and the `A`).

How am I supposed to set `((char*)ptr)[0]` equal to 1? I'm pretty lost on this right now.

Comment: So far, what you have is a memory leak. C pointers aren't Java or C# references. If all you're doing is evaluating content at some memory location, `malloc` is likely already wrong, as there should be no need to acquire additional memory.  And you can't peel out the lead digit of a decimal value like you're trying without additional code.

Comment: `((char*)ptr)[0]` is the first character of the string, so it's `102`, not the first digit of 102.

Comment: You would create a string with the first element == 1 with `"\1"`

Answer (score 1):

This code is not doing what you think it does. THe compiler must be screaming at you about it.

```
void* ptr = malloc(4);
char* temp = "f";
ptr = temp;
```

I think you are trying to allocate a 4 byte buffer and then set the first byte of that buffer to "f"

```
void* ptr = malloc(4);
*((char*)ptr) = 'f';
```

The first line allocates 4 bytes and puts the pointer to it in `ptr`

Second line says , treat ptr as a char ptr, put 'f' where that char pointer points.

Easier to read is

```
// make a copy of ptr saying its a char ptr
char *temp = (char*)ptr;
// store f where it points
*temp = 'f'
```

Note 'f' not "f". These are 2 different things

- 'f' is the single char = hex 0x66 or decimal 102 (https://www.asciitable.com/)
- "f" is a character string composed of 2 bytes 'f' and '\0'

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the proper way to check if the first character is a 1 is `((char*)ptr)[0] == 1`.

> I recently learned that it compares their ASCII values.

In C, character values are just integers.  For example, the character literal `'f'` is 102 (assuming you're using ASCII).  That means the following is perfectly valid.

```c
int x = 'f';

if ( x > 100 ) {
    printf("Greater than 100\n");
}
```

It's not the case that the first character is 1, the second 0, and the third 2.  `'f'` and 102 are the same thing.

On a side note (but a very important one), you've got a memory leak in your code, as @WhozCraig pointed out in the comments.  You're assigning `ptr` to `malloc(4)` but then reassigning `ptr` to `temp`.  Therefore, the four bytes allocated by the `malloc` call are lost.

You can just do

```c
void *ptr;
char *temp = "f";
ptr = temp;
```

Comment: Re “the character literal `'f'` is 102”: This is not part of the C standard. The standard allows other character encodings to be used. ASCII is common but is not the only character encoding.

Comment: They want it to equal `1`, not `'f'`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify character codes in a string using octal or hexadecimal escape sequences. So the following will create a string whose first byte is `1` and will satisfy the test in your code.

```
char *f = "\1"; // or "\x1"
```